# Managing labels of specific points at equal spacing in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

My `Test.dat` file is given below

```
# Experimental data 
# Col 1:2: -0.20 V 
# Col 3:4: -0.50 V 
# Col 5:6: -0.60 V 
# Col 7:8: -0.80 V                          
# Col 9:10: -0.20 V-Fit 
# Col 11:12: -0.50 V-Fit
# Col 13:14: -0.60 V-Fit
# Col 15:16: -0.80 V-Fit
# Col 17: Frequency (Hz)
5.3482      7.19036         5.19009     4.69308         4.81642     4.65453         4.0498      2.40795         5.31334     7.06889         5.25193     4.9429          4.84544     4.70025         4.16655     2.37037         2999.961376
5.52344     7.90454         5.39068     5.16668         4.97274     5.12448         4.11048     2.65712         5.49548     7.81383         5.46959     5.36954         5.00025     5.16492         4.21479     2.63018         2670.228481
5.71967     8.69132         5.62205     5.65348         5.14765     5.61955         4.17784     2.93241         5.69934     8.63597         5.70749     5.83187         5.17218     5.67442         4.26891     2.91798         2376.85442
5.94678     9.58147         5.87582     6.17915         5.34049     6.18747         4.25381     3.23767         5.92783     9.54365         5.96773     6.33299         5.36333     6.2332          4.32969     3.23692         2115.666866
6.19812     10.56199        6.15759     6.74797         5.56659     6.82112         4.33771     3.57603         6.18405     10.54516        6.2524      6.87578         5.5759      6.84562         4.39794     3.59018         1883.208752
6.4801      11.64968        6.46991     7.3617          5.80584     7.49994         4.43019     3.95101         6.47162     11.64985        6.56387     7.46345         5.81241     7.51651         4.47458     3.98138         1676.32103
6.79736     12.85491        6.81988     8.02473         6.07441     8.24057         4.53525     4.36556         6.79479     12.86846        6.90491     8.09969         6.07581     8.25144         4.56071     4.41467         1492.112875
7.15229     14.18271        7.20016     8.73162         6.36887     9.04089         4.65162     4.82603         7.15829     14.2122         7.27841     8.78816         6.36931     9.05612         4.65752     4.89448         1328.110695
7.55191     15.6586         7.62896     9.50105         6.70172     9.92601         4.78082     5.33289         7.56723     15.69226        7.68728     9.53223         6.69625     9.93604         4.76627     5.42529         1182.198524
8.00034     17.27448        8.1015      10.32809        7.07033     10.88906        4.91718     5.89422         8.02797     17.32279        8.13528     10.33644        7.06085     10.89831        4.88853     6.01278         1052.290201
8.50314     19.06022        8.62248     11.19793        7.48534     11.94557        5.07426     6.5306          8.54733     19.11752        8.62609     11.20482        7.46746     11.94958        5.02597     6.66261         936.6720915
9.07294     21.03544        9.20331     12.1393         7.95412     13.10161        5.25139     7.22931         9.13346     21.0926         9.16409     12.14216        7.92123     13.09767        5.18054     7.38146         833.73487
9.73628     23.1993         9.83493     13.16506        8.46833     14.36015        5.46385     8.01308         9.79517     23.26395        9.75373     13.15281        8.42758     14.35005        5.35433     8.17616         742.1225309
10.46662    25.58418        10.53342    14.27584        9.04938     15.7331         5.68565     8.8891          10.54288    25.64997        10.40018    14.24189        8.99281     15.7154         5.54982     9.05466         660.5684757
11.30874    28.21501        11.29144    15.48928        9.68926     17.24048        5.93471     9.86026         11.38806    28.26924        11.10883    15.41417        9.62368     17.20217        5.76967     10.02529        587.9849195
12.25349    31.10186        12.13787    16.77338        10.40666    18.87136        6.21695     10.91931        12.34401    31.14258        11.88582    16.675          10.32789    18.81986        6.017       11.09755        523.3734846
13.33057    34.25004        13.05039    18.12576        11.21145    20.63749        6.52501     12.08398        13.4254     34.29099        12.73752    18.02938        11.11367    20.57776        6.29518     12.28144        465.8699036
14.52877    37.72834        14.05746    19.58011        12.09233    22.54544        6.87277     13.37298        14.64928    37.73827        13.6713     19.48306        11.99046    22.4864         6.60819     13.58853        414.6769643
15.9318     41.50195        15.16613    21.13292        13.09156    24.62451        7.26236     14.7933         16.03428    41.50795        14.69473    21.0412         12.96823    24.55592        6.96033     15.03089        369.1092134
17.48885    45.62211        16.34935    22.7757         14.19823    26.87261        7.68792     16.35034        17.60142    45.62514        15.81609    22.70913        14.05795    26.79702        7.35651     16.62195        328.5482526
19.27369    50.12233        17.67077    24.53066        15.43615    29.30286        8.17511     18.10514        19.37369    50.115          17.04405    24.49177        15.27128    29.22019        7.80212     18.37601        292.4501896
21.24715    55.05442        19.06097    26.34819        16.77768    31.88924        8.70788     20.00099        21.37788    55.00665        18.38872    26.3951         16.62166    31.8378         8.30357     20.30993        260.3083849
23.54249    60.33315        20.60387    28.36038        18.30648    34.74565        9.31817     22.14781        23.64101    60.32401        19.85923    28.42264        18.12186    34.65932        8.86739     22.43973        231.7093313
26.11       66.12278        22.22766    30.45975        19.9147     37.75172        9.97577     24.48379        26.19549    66.09801        21.46706    30.58012        19.78736    37.69781        9.50167     24.7856         206.2469721
28.96331    72.36502        24.00729    32.66478        21.78825    40.99738        10.74694    27.08102        29.07368    72.35337        23.22244    32.8705         21.63268    40.96305        10.21468    27.36679        183.5897565
32.14917    78.81115        25.81999    35.0394         23.66136    44.5305         11.5696     29.81697        32.31496    79.12417        25.13871    35.29976        23.67595    44.4698         11.01685    30.20826        163.4098589
35.8012     87.27192        27.72862    37.95827        25.60681    48.59571        12.10952    32.83374        35.95462    86.43017        27.22557    37.86825        25.93176    48.22555        11.91806    33.331          145.457685
40.0451     94.46327        30.09316    40.11188        28.56734    51.9632         13.48607    36.53042        40.03846    94.30707        29.4977     40.58166        28.42045    52.24634        12.93148    36.76505        129.468739
44.3986     103.02569       32.65008    42.71365        31.26175    56.30807        14.71726    40.25237        44.60387    102.7694        31.964      43.43792        31.1564     56.53787        14.06905    40.5337         115.249306
49.41737    112.13202       35.08782    45.50361        34.194      60.78231        16.0259     44.25363        49.70523    111.85906       34.64155    46.44396        34.16358    61.12027        15.34799    44.67509        102.5795937
55.34925    121.87463       37.90832    48.52652        37.35213    65.53601        17.53973    48.83812        55.38206    121.58704       37.5385     49.59602        37.45653    65.99879        16.78315    49.21638        91.30872786
61.76343    132.12764       40.7851     51.68467        40.97616    70.53955        19.14158    53.82411        61.68653    131.98417       40.66873    52.89664        41.05688    71.18949        18.39413    54.19674        81.27465844
68.78138    143.52929       44.08481    55.09847        44.71328    76.04811        21.07635    59.25515        68.66518    143.06976       44.0424     56.34442        44.98287    76.70357        20.20096    59.65304        72.3451376
76.80008    155.39493       47.55355    58.51519        49.01537    81.63447        23.06471    65.43016        76.37021    154.87122       47.67158    59.94029        49.25591    82.55725        22.22732    65.62928        64.3953681
85.04398    167.73903       51.35647    62.37713        53.53357    88.19325        25.30311    71.80395        84.84864    167.40793       51.56509    63.68254        53.89476    88.76372        24.49798    72.16859        57.3201105
93.17163    181.47175       55.4862     65.51628        58.30892    93.54346        27.75073    79.63989        94.15319    180.70873       55.73362    67.57226        58.92174    95.34187        27.04206    79.32203        51.02064461
105.52235   196.45335       59.61517    70.90046        63.46267    101.01341       31.17511    86.25563        104.32725   194.79092       60.1829     71.60712        64.35476    102.3058        29.88918    87.13741        45.41501403
115.97845   210.39987       64.25769    74.68956        69.99201    108.74659       34.43525    95.59453        115.42434   209.68876       64.9224     75.78982        70.21792    109.67881       33.07517    95.67445        40.42405635
127.53986   225.13431       69.08642    79.4471         76.11767    117.28668       37.65949    105.68054       127.48918   225.42762       69.95699    80.12068        76.53155    117.48054       36.63702    104.99037       35.98164767
140.92206   242.20678       74.4551     83.9174         83.09223    125.49658       42.06106    115.69072       140.56961   242.04104       75.29214    84.60265        83.31863    125.73521       40.61647    115.14915       32.02725202
154.75829   259.83691       80.12594    89.0169         90.52148    134.54984       46.42489    127.68276       154.70844   259.5605        80.93057    89.23859        90.60061    134.46639       45.05776    126.21507       28.50824967
170.2029    277.82716       86.32966    94.3355         98.44053    144.18299       51.69251    139.83987       169.9593    278.03527       86.8786     94.03665        98.40554    143.70675       50.01278    138.26493       25.37528053
186.20771   298.06654       93.52445    99.54897        107.09589   153.85211       57.93742    153.12209       186.36272   297.50293       93.13671    99.0026         106.7558    153.48316       55.53356    151.36904       22.5873664
204.86235   317.13551       100.81275   105.36231       116.694     164.6805        64.21005    168.04675       203.97549   318.02476       99.71103    104.14908       115.68302   163.83429       61.68197    165.61404       20.10539174
220.57758   340.78877       108.51106   111.40893       126.84103   175.86559       71.48759    183.79241       222.85457   339.66556       106.60699   109.49035       125.21973   174.8004        68.52485    181.09001       17.89536327
242.3968    360.39263       117.40936   117.6596        136.69333   186.7789        81.70404    202.5117        243.03667   362.47065       113.82225   115.03682       135.38902   186.41157       76.12606    197.87284       15.92934132
266.83533   389.26741       126.17557   122.92684       148.57675   199.86182       86.17534    220.65631       264.59964   386.53504       121.36894   120.81201       146.2354    198.7227        84.56936    216.07449       14.17868771
286.34931   417.16655       134.61015   129.07056       161.79998   212.47665       98.31536    242.33905       287.59336   411.92448       129.24892   126.83321       157.78981   211.77344       93.93262    235.78526       12.62081787
300.73191   426.3048        143.90888   135.00097       175.51268   227.28968       110.29048   262.88944       312.10175   438.74422       137.47559   133.12797       170.10074   225.62325       104.31203   257.12554       11.2336129
329.48549   466.70438       153.15023   141.41269       189.21756   241.40532       121.01086   287.63574       338.16866   467.0569        146.04889   139.7147        183.19689   240.3092        115.79139   280.18137       9.999843314
```

The Gnuplot code is given below

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced colour font 'Times-Bold,12' size 4in,4in  
set output "EIS-Test.eps"

set style line 1 lt 1 lw 5 lc rgb "red"
set style line 2 lt 2 lw 5 lc rgb "#0008B"
set style line 3 lt 3 lw 5 lc rgb "#006400"
set style line 4 lt 4 lw 5 lc rgb "#8A2BE2"
set style line 5 lt 5 lw 5 lc rgb "dark-magenta"
set style line 6 lt 6 lw 5 lc rgb "#000FF"
set style line 7 lt 7 lw 5 lc rgb "#00008B"
set style line 8 lt 8 lw 5 lc rgb "#483D8B"


set xtics out scale 1.5 
set ytics out scale 1.5
set tics font ", 16"
set xlabel "{/Times-Italic Z}_{Re} ({/Symbol \127}. cm^{-2})"  font ",16"
set ylabel "{/Times-Italic -Z}_{Im} ({/Symbol \127}. cm^{-2})" font ",16"
set key inside left top   
set key samplen 5 spacing 1.85 font ",16" width -1.0

plot [0:500] 'Test.dat' u 1:2 w points pt 1 ps 1.5 lt -1 title "-0.20 V", \
'' u 3:4 w points pt 2 ps 1.5 lt -1 title "-0.50 V", \
'' u 5:6 w points pt 3 ps 1.5  lt -1 title "-0.60 V", \
'' u 7:8 w points pt 4 ps 1.5 lt -1 title "-0.80 V", \
'' u 9:10 w l ls 6 title "Fit", \
'' u 11:12 w l ls 6 notitle, \
'' u 13:14 w l ls 6 notitle, \
'' u 15:16 w l ls 6 notitle
```

The plot looks fine. Now, the data file, the last column (17th column) is the frequency at which the data sets were acquired in an impedance measurement. That is, Col 1:2 at -0.20 v, Col 3:4 at -0.50 V and so on (first 8 columns are experimental data) were recorded in a specific frequency range (3000-10 Hz). Columns 9 to 16 corresponds to non-linear fits to each data set and as one see, the fit is good.

Now, I wish to label each data set (1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8) with the frequency but with a condition that every 10th frequency should be labelled to the specific data point after rounding it off. How can I revise the script and automate this in Gnuplot? I have provided a small data set, the actual data set is very large.

Answer (score 0):

There is the plotting style `with labels` (check `help labels`) and check `help every` to plot every 10th datapoint (label).

As you can see in your case, towards zero the labels are getting too dense. So, you might think about another way to organize these labels (e.g. log-log-plot or even less than every 10th label, ...)

**Code:** (to be added)

```
set style textbox opaque

plot 
# ...your original plot command code...
'' u 1:2:(sprintf("%.0f",$17)) every 10::9 w labels offset 0,1 boxed notitle, \
'' u 3:4:(sprintf("%.0f",$17)) every 10::9 w labels offset 0,1 boxed notitle, \
'' u 5:6:(sprintf("%.0f",$17)) every 10::9 w labels offset 0,1 boxed notitle, \
'' u 7:8:(sprintf("%.0f",$17)) every 10::9 w labels offset 0,1 boxed notitle
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: you might want to set `set style textbox opaque noborder` if you don't like the border around the labels.

Comment: Thank you for the code. Is it possible to have less dense labels near zero (say every 10 data points) and more dense labels near 300 at the end of the curve (say every 5 data points).

Comment: well, this can somehow be done, but towards zero it will stay "crowded", i.e. labels will still be on top of each other since all 4 curves converge. You could color the points or lines via color palette as a logarithmic function of frequency. I tried this, but also doesn't look very clear since everything is very dense towards zero.